# how to receive sms in kotlin and send mesage to flutter

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

I can create a method in kotlin and use it in flutter but I want to receive SMS in kotlin and when coming SMS change UI in flutter.
How can I do this? anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Event channel -> This is helpful if you want to send data to flutter every time a particular event occurs on android native side.

### Updated:--

MainActiviy.kt

```
class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {

private val eventChannelName = "com.example.events_broadcast/eventChannelName"

private val tag = "MainActivity"

private val smsReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    private var listener: OnSmsReceivedListener? = null

    fun setListener(onSmsReceivedListener: OnSmsReceivedListener) {
        listener = onSmsReceivedListener
    }

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        when (intent?.action) {
            "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" -> {
                listener!!.onReceivedSms()
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun getIntentFilter(): IntentFilter {
    val iFilter = IntentFilter()
    iFilter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")
    return iFilter
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    registerReceiver(smsReceiver, getIntentFilter())
}

override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    unregisterReceiver(smsReceiver)
}

override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
    super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
    EventChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, eventChannelName).setStreamHandler(
        object : EventChannel.StreamHandler {
            private var eventSink: EventChannel.EventSink? = null

            override fun onListen(p0: Any?, sink: EventChannel.EventSink) {
                eventSink = sink
                smsReceiver.setListener(object : OnSmsReceivedListener() {
                    var count: Int = 0
                    override fun onReceivedSms() {
                        count++;
                        eventSink?.success(count)
                    }
                })
            }
            override fun onCancel(p0: Any?) {
                eventSink = null
            }
        }
    )

}
    }
```

abstract class

```
abstract class OnSmsReceivedListener {
abstract fun onReceivedSms()
}
```

Add permission in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
```

In main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';


Stream<int> streamCounterFromNative() {
 const counterChannel =
   
EventChannel("com.example.events_broadcast/eventChannelName");
return counterChannel.receiveBroadcastStream().map((event) {
return int.parse(event.toString());
});
}

void main() {
runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
 const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
 }

 class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text("HIII"),
  ),
  body: Center(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
     
        StreamBuilder<int>(
          stream: streamCounterFromNative(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Text(
                '${snapshot.data}',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
              );
            } else {
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
)
);
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: how to use event Chanel in broadcast? when SMS comes the broadcast receiver method is called and i should change flutter ui

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I have updated my answer.