# How do I stream android hardware buttons from android native code to flutter app?

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin, dart

I want to get the string value of the name of physical button pressed from android native code and pass it to flutter app. I used eventchannel to send data from kotlin code to dart code.

I tried to stream key-event action using eventchannel.

Here is my dart code:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  String batteryStatus = "Streaming...";
  static const chargingChannel = EventChannel('nthunya.com/physicalButton');
  late StreamSubscription _streamSubscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    
    onStreamBattery();

  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _streamSubscription.cancel();
  }

  void onStreamBattery(){
    _streamSubscription =
    chargingChannel.receiveBroadcastStream().listen((event){
      setState((){ batteryStatus = '$event';});
    });
    
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Hardware buttons find'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Button name: $batteryStatus\n'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is kotlin code:

```
package com.example.flutter_panic_button1000

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.IntentFilter
import android.view.KeyEvent
import android.widget.Toast
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.EventChannel

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {

    private val KEY_PRESS = "nthunya.com/physicalButton"
    private lateinit var eventChannel: EventChannel

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)

        eventChannel = EventChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, KEY_PRESS)
        eventChannel.setStreamHandler(MyStreamHandler(context))
    }
}

class MyStreamHandler(private val context: Context) : EventChannel.StreamHandler{
    private var receiver: BroadcastReceiver? = null

    override fun onListen(arguments: Any?, events: EventChannel.EventSink?) {
        if (events == null) return

        receiver = initReceiver(events)
        context.registerReceiver(receiver, IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON))
    }

    private fun initReceiver(events: EventChannel.EventSink): BroadcastReceiver? {

        return object : BroadcastReceiver(){
            override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {

                when(intent?.getIntExtra(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN.toString(),-1)){
                    KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN -> events.success("Volume down")
                    KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP-> events.success("Volume up")
                }
            }

        }
    }

    override fun onCancel(arguments: Any?) {
        context.unregisterReceiver(receiver)
        receiver = null
    }
}
```

The program runs without errors, but it doesn't display the name of button pressed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74072997/14071053