Reliable way to receive SMS messages in the background and foreground with Flutter
I'm building a Flutter app that needs to receive SMS messages in the background and foreground, even when the app is closed or running.
Query 1:
How to receive SMS messages in Flutter, both in the background and foreground?
I have implemented background and foreground functionality in Flutter using the telephony package, but I'm experiencing a bug where I can't consistently catch SMS messages. Sometimes it works in the background, and sometimes in the foreground.

This is possible in android only, https://stackoverflow.com/a/74072997/14071053  In this link you will see the updated (int) value on flutter screen whenever a new message appears. So, try this first then read the sms at android side and return it to flutter (just like the integer). For background you may need to create background services at android side.

@Aks
Thanks, I will review that answer
